# Tensorflow: NameError: name 'x_train' is not defined

Tags: python, tensorflow

I'm new into tensorflow. I'm receiving this error...

> Traceback (most recent call last):
>   File "C:\Users\s\Desktop\linear.py", line 36, in 
>   sess.run(train, {x: x_train, y: y_train})
>   NameError: name 'x_train' is not defined

My Code:

```
import tensorflow as tf

# y = mx + b

#Model input and output
x = tf.placeholder(tf.float32)
y = tf.placeholder(tf.float32)

# Model parameter
m = tf.Variable([.3], tf.float32)
b = tf.Variable([-.3], tf.float32)

linear_model = m * x + b

# Loss function
loss = tf.reduce_sum(tf.square(linear_model - y))

#optimizer
optimizer = tf.train.GradientDescentOptimizer(0.01)
train = optimizer.minimize(loss)

#training data 
x_data = [1,2,3,4]
y_data = [0,-1,-2,-3]

# Run session
sess = tf.Session()
init = tf.global_variables_initializer()
sess.run(init)

#tTensorboard
writer = tf.summary.FileWriter('./graphs', sess.graph)

# highest value for range is 25,000
for i in range(1000):
    sess.run(train, {x: x_train, y: y_train})
    # evaluation
    curr_m, curr_b, curr_loss = sess.run([m,b,loss], {x: x_train, y: y_train})
    # print 
    print("%s, %s, %s"%(curr_m, curr_b, curr_loss))

writer.close()
```

[This is the screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iifIu.png)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You do not have a variable/tensor `x_train`: this is why you get an error

> ```
> NameError: name 'x_train' is not defined
> ```

Did you mean `x_data`?

Comment: Didn't noticed the variable. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

I guess you meant to have `x_data` not `x_train`

However, in general, this is not a problem from tensorflow. It is a flaw in your code. This code bellow will produce the same error and it does not use tensorflow

```
p = "rr"
print x
```

As it is clear that I am using the variable x before defining it.